# Why radial gradient in d3 changes when the height/width of the svg container is not the same as the height/width?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, radial-gradients

I am trying to understand how the radial gradient in d3.js works. I have a circle and I filled it with the radial gradient specified in 'defs' tag. I set the 'r' coordinate of the radial gradient to be 60% and 'cx' and 'cy' to be zero. My understanding is the radial gradient will always start from 0,0 coordinate (exactly in the middle of my circle element) and the outer circle of the radial gradient will "stop" at 60%  of my "r". Now when I change only the width of my svg container and leave the height unchanged the radial gradient is not the same. It seems like the outer circle of the radial gradient is pushed away. I cannot understand why is this happening. I spent hours searching online but I could not find sufficient answer. Is it possible to maintain the shape of  the radial gradient when the height or width is changed?

[picture 1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyDVV.jpg)
This picture explains what I actually want to achieve. I want to fill the arc with the gradient. I think I need to use "userSpaceOnUse" for gradient units because I am filling this radial gradient into individual segments as shown here [picture 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ZjL.jpg). I tried to use objectBoundingBox instead but what I got as a result was an individual radial gradient got filled in each segment.(aka circle in each segment). When I change the height/width of the container the outer circle of the radial gradient gets pushed away so the arc colour actually loses the gradient effect. This is why I am trying to find out a way of maintaining the shape of the radial gradient when the height/width gets changed.

Thanks
This is my code:

```
var w = 1000, h = 1000
r = Math.min(w, h) /4 ;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" +Math.min(w,h)/2 + "," +Math.min(w,h) /2     + ")");

var radialGradient = d3.select("svg").append("defs")
  .append("radialGradient")
  .attr("id", "radial-gradient")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", "60%") 
  .attr("spreadMethod", "reflect");

radialGradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "15%")
  .attr("stop-color", "red");

radialGradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "25%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#fff");

radialGradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "35%")
  .attr("stop-color", "red");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", r)
  .style("fill", "url(#radial-gradient)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You has set the center of gradient to (cx,cy) 0,0 the origin of container and tell use container space: userSpaceOnUse.

To correct this, just change to:

```
 .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")    // your object limits
  .attr("cx", "50%")
  .attr("cy", "50%")                             // your object center
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Klaujesi. Unfortunately I really need to use the userSpaceOnUse for gradient units. I have edited my question and added more details and pictures to explain in more details what my problem is.

Comment: you can achieve this using 1 general gradiente (objectBoundingBox)  + mask

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide an example please? Or maybe some links so I can read more about this technique?? Thank you very much.